# Angular2 Error trying to upload image to Lumen backend

Tags: laravel, angular, lumen

I am trying to upload an image to my database as a blob (I know its bad practice but I have to). The error I keep getting is `Call to a member function openFile() on null`

My form

```
<form ngNoForm action="http://Api.app/api/v1/uploadImage" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

My Controller in Lumen

```
class ImageUploadController extends Controller {

    public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $contents = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize());

        $die = DB::table('paint')->find(1);

        $die->pic = $contents;
        $die->save();
    }

}
```

My route

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
});

$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function($app) {
        $app->post('/uploadImage', [
            'uses' => 'ImageUploadController@uploadImage'
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specific the content type as "multipart/form-data" for the post.

```
<form ngNoForm action="http://Api.app/api/v1/uploadImage" 
               target="_blank" 
               method="POST" 
               enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```